# bash script to find unique value in a file with index

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file ,test.txt, like

```
shekhar cbv
ravi cbv
ravi sdf
asd df
ravi Df
ravi dfg
ravi df
ravi dfg
ravi df
afas cvb
sdf hgh
sasdg cfg
```

I want to sort based on 2nd field and want to write 2nd field only on "result.txt"
 Currently I am doing following:

sort -k 2,2 test.txt| uniq -i -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f2 > result.txt

which is writing 2n field i.e.

```
cbv 
cfg 
cvb 
df  
dfg 
hgh 
sdf
```

Corresponding to every unique 2nd field value I want its,all, index in original file. 
How this is possible ?

Desired Output:

```
cbv 1 2
cfg 12
cvb 10
df 4 5 7 9 
dfg 6 8
hgh 11
sdf 3
```

One more thing if say there is 3rd field also. How to achieve the above only mean while sorting and finding uniqueness only 2nd field is used.

input With 3rd field

```
    shekhar cbv rg
    ravi cbv fdf
    ravi sdf dfh
    asd df dfhdfh
    ravi Df fgh
    ravi dfg dfh
    ravi df dfgh
    ravi dfg dfgh
    ravi df dfhg
    afas cvb fhfg
    sdf hgh cgfhfg
    sasdg cfg fgh
```

Desired o/p same .
Thanks, 
Ravi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command to print column with **all original indexes**:

```
awk '{k=tolower($2); arr[k]=arr[k] " " NR} END{for(v in arr) print v, arr[v]}' test.txt | sort -f -k 1,1
```

#### OUTPUT

```
cbv  1 2
cfg  12
cvb  10
df  4 5 7 9
dfg  6 8
hgh  11
sdf  3
```

### Update: using awk only solution

```
awk '{k=tolower($2); arr[k]=arr[k] " " NR} END{n=asorti(arr, dest); for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) print dest[i], arr[dest[i]]}' test.txt
```

Your file can have any number of columns but this command will only look at 2nd column.

Comment: This gives only 1st index, I want all index associated.

Comment: @jm666 Yes I noticed that too but since OP wanted unique values so I provided this answer which obviously discards other two occurrences of the string `df`.

Comment: @Ravi Your problem didn't clearly state that but let me see what I can do.

Comment: Can you pls add an example output in your question?

Comment: I have updated my question, one more constrain regarding 3rd field.

Comment: @ravi - people here investing time to finding solution for you. Please, don't change the question every time, because this brings unnecessary double work. Simply show your input and the wanted output, but the whole problem.

Comment: thanks, anubhava. Solved.I will manually remove 3rd parameter, for time being.

Comment: @jm666 - I will try to formulate proper question from next time

Comment: You're welcome, fyi I added one more command to get same output but using 100% awk without any piping to `sort`, `uniq` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `cut` to extract the column you want and then do the `sort` and `uniq` stuff:

```
cut -f2 -d' ' test.txt | sort -f | uniq -i > result.txt
```

This assumes that the columns are separated by a single space.

Note that you'll want `-f` switch on `sort` so that the sorting will be case insensitive, otherwise rows that differ only in case won't be beside each other and `uniq -i` probably won't do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're so close! To get the value of the second column based on what you've done so far, you should use [awk](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/awk.html). It is made for processing a stream line by line and extracting just the parts you want.

Your code: `sort -k 2,2 test.txt| uniq -i -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f2 > result.txt`

With awk: `sort -k 2,2 test.txt| uniq -i -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f2 | awk '{print $2}' > result.txt`

Awk will split your input by whitespace, and `print $2` will take the second text block. I'd recommend looking into awk - it is great for many problems.

Answer (score 1):

For fun - perl:

```
perl -anle 'push(@{$s{$F[1]}},++$n);END{map{print "$_: @{$s{$_}}"} sort keys %s}'
```

or case insensitive

```
perl -anle 'push(@{$s{lc($F[1])}},++$n);END{map{print "$_: @{$s{$_}}"} sort keys %s}'
```